# Why are the properties and methods created in a function not shown in the constructor property of the prototype of that function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function protoFunc(name) {
    this.name;
    this.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Here I create a constructor. Now, this constructor has a prototype property that contains an object on which you define members, i.e. methods and properties, that you want to be inherited. One of those members is the 'constructor' property, which points to the function itself.

So, why is it then that neither inside the prototype property, nor inside the constructor property, I don't see the methods and properties that I just created inside the function?

I just see this:

```
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 1
name: "protoFunc"
prototype:
    constructor: ƒ protoFunc(name)
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: ƒ ()
```

Where is the method that I just created?

Comment: Because these are not added *to the prototype*. They are added directly to each instance.

Comment: @VLAZ Okay, can I ask you 3 more questions? Why do instances not have the `prototype` property? Is that property available only to `constructors`? Also, I know that, when I invoke a function without the `new` keyword, I am invoking it as a function, not a constructor, so it returns 'undefined' if it only has properties & methods, but why when I do the same for build-in objects like `String()` or `Number()`, why do I get the value that I added in the parentheses? Why does it not return `undefined` again? Lastly, is the default `Object` a Class, or just a function constructor again?

Comment: `prototype` is only for constructor functions. It's what that constructor will use to make *more* items. All constructed items get the constructor's prototype and through it access to methods and properties. Instances might have a `__proto__` property but it's (sort of) deprecated. You can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` to get the prototype chain of an instance.

Comment: `Number` and `String` are implemented differently. You can achieve a similar behaviour - there are ways to check if a function was called with or without `new` like [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) and then you can provide a different `return` when it's not called with `new`.

Comment: As for Object. You can certainly call it a class. It's also a constructor function but it's slightly special, since it's in the specs and it's usually host provided. Which means that if you want to fully emulate what it does, you need to read the specs and do the same things. But it's not special in terms of actions it makes - anything it does can be implemented in JS.

Comment: Thanks. So, I have one more thing that confuses me a bit. I already asked it to the other user, but since he hasn't responded it, I will reiterate it to you, hoping you can give me an answer. So, instances inherit from all 3 - the constructor function, the prototype property of the constructor function, and from the prototype object from the constructor function? Is that correct? Also, does the prototype object of the constructor function inherit from the prototype property of the default global Object, from the default Object's constructor function, or the default Object's prototype object?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why when I type `Object.__proto__` I get `ƒ () { [native code] }` this? Shouldn't I get access to the prototype object of the global Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've written doesn't add anything to the prototype. Instead, it adds properties to each instance. In other words, if someone calls

```
const a = new protoFunc('bob');
```

then `a` will have a `.name` and a `.getName` property directly on it. It doesn't get these via the prototype chain, and they don't exist before you call `new`.

If you want `getName` to be on the prototype chain, you need to change your code to this:

```
function protoFunc(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

protoFunc.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
}
```

Note: i changed the line in protoFunc that said `this.name` to `this.name = name`, since that's probably what you meant to do.

Comment: So, the `constructor` property then only shows the methods and properties of the function, but the `this.name` and `this.getName()` are not on the function, they are .. what? I get that they are to be added on each new instance, but don't they still exist on the `constructor`? Or are you saying that, they exist on the `body` of the function, but they are not methods and properties, and that's why they're not shown?

Comment: Can I ask you 3 more questions? Why do instances not have the `prototype` property? Is that property available only to constructors? Also, I know that, when I invoke a function without the `new` keyword, I am invoking it as a function, not a constructor, so it returns `undefined` if it only has properties & methods, but why when I do the same for build-in objects like` String()` or `Number()`, why do I get the value that I added in the parentheses? Why does it not return `undefined` again? Lastly, is the default `Object` a Class, or just a function constructor again?

Comment: `the this.name and this.getName() are not on the function, they are .. what?` Until you call `new protoFunc`, they are just lines of code that havn't been run yet. Once you run them, they will add properties onto `this`, where this is the instance of the object (ie, `a` in my code).

Comment: `Why do instances not have the prototype property?` Because they don't need it. `prototype` is something that constructor functions need. When you call `new`, the new operator will look for the `prototype` property on the function and use that when creating the new object. After that point, a different mechanism is used than `.prototype`. If you want to find out the prototype of an instance, use [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Comment: `why when I do the same for build-in objects like String() or Number(), why do I get the value that I added in the parentheses?` Because that's how the language defines the String and Number functions. I'm not sure what more i can add. `Lastly, is the default Object a Class, or just a function constructor again?` There isn't really a difference. classes are (mostly) just syntatic sugar for constructors with prototypes.

Comment: @IloveCoffee A related answer of mine that touches on much in your subsequent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30060630/710446

Comment: @NicholasTower Is a `constructor` in JS the same as a `Class` in Java? For build-in objects, why are the methods & properties all stored in the `prototype` property, rather than on the `function constructor` itself?

Comment: `Is a constructor in JS the same as a Class in Java` There are similarities, but they use a completely different approach for inheritence. `For build-in objects, why are the methods & properties all stored in the prototype property` Anything that's supposed to be inherited must go on the prototype. So i guess the properties you're asking about are all ones that are inherited.

Comment: So, objects, or instances, inherit first from the constructor, and then from the prototype property, and then also from the prototype object as well? This is a little bit confusing to me. If new instances inherit from the prototype property of their constructor, then what is the role of their prototype object? Does their prototype object inherit from the prototype property of the default global Object, from the default Object's constructor, or the default Object's property object?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out why when I type `Object.__proto__` I get `ƒ () { [native code] }` this? Shouldn't I get access to the property object of the global Object? Sorry if these questions deviated so much from the main one. I'm just trying to make sense of all this, and build a clear complete picture of this in my head.

Answer (score 0):

if i define methods like this(in the body of  the constructor function ) it would not add the methods to the protoyype chain that we mean.
by doing this (wrong) manner , its like we are coping the methods everytime by creating every instance ,
we shoulndt do this , because its silly . its not OOP at all , our purspose is adding method once to prototype and inherit that any time smartly , not coping same functions and methods every time

It is better for us to inherit something than to carry it with us every time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).